# how to write buffer for compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, buffer

I want to write compiler with C# for the first time and I somehow lost what to do about its buffering! My reference is *Compilers, Principles, Techniques and Tools,* and it says:

> Because of the amount of time taken to process characters and the
>   large number of characters that must be processed during the
>   compilation of a large source program, specialized buffering
>   techniques have been developed to reduce the amount of overhead
>   required to process a single input character.An important scheme
>   involves two buffers that are alternately reloaded,Each buffer is of
>   the same size N, and N is usually the size of a disk block,e.g., 4096
>   bytes. Using one system read command we can read N characters into a
>   buffer, rather than using one system call per character. If fewer than
>   N characters remain in the input file, then a special character,
>   represented by eof,marks the end of the source file and is different
>   from any possible character of the source program.

and it also said in this book that we put **eof** at the end of each buffer to realize that we reach the end of buffer.and it has two pointers **forward** and **lexemBegine** that points to the lexeme in buffer!
my problem is that I don't know how to create this buffer ? should I make array or buffer with the size N in sourceBuffer class and then how can I read file from StreamReader and put N characters of source file into array ?
what is the problem if I read characters from source file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you reference the last edition of "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" from 1986. (But even at that time the quoted part was already outdated).

In modern programming languages like C# (or more precisely in its I/O library) this kind of buffering is already implemented (in a robust, tested, high performance way).

Just use `StreamReader` which does all this work for you. Then just read character after character until you found a complete token, then process your tokens as described in this excellent book.

Comment: Inspection of the use of `StreamReader`'s internal `charBuffer` property at [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,6f72965f85c37ebf,references) shows some of the implementation aspects foreseen in the book

Comment: oh,thanks so much ,it is because of this I become totally confused !I always use StreamReader but I didn't know this point !